# Manually open jQuery UI Tooltip with mouse tracking enabled

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

If you see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattblang/yfYhu/10/) you will notice that in order to spawn the Tooltip the mouse has to leave and reenter the div `foo` after the Tooltip has been initialized.

I thought that maybe I could manually trigger the Tooltip using `tooltip("open")`.  Unfortunately, the mouse tracking doesn't work when I do that.  See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattblang/yfYhu/8/).

Does anyone have an idea how I could get the Tooltip to open with mouse tracking enabled without having to leave and reenter the div?  In case you are wondering why I need to do this, I am working with WebGL in a `canvas` element that takes up the entire screen.

Comment: I created a [bug ticket](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9214).

Answer (score 1):

I am using the `track: true` option and I faced to the same problem in a different context. I am working with richfaces and have some ajax calls which rerender parts of a page.

After each rerender, i needed to rebuild tooltips present in the rerendered part so i decided to attach an event handler to the document and to rebuild thoses tooltips on mouseenter, and then manually open them by calling `$(...).tooltip('open')`... tooltips are displayed correctly but the mouse tracking doesn't work anymore.

So instead of using `$(...).tooltip('open')`, i trigger a mouseenter event and work with css class to init only once :

```
jQuery(document).on('mouseenter', '.tt', function() {
    jQuery(this).tooltip({
        content: function() { ... },
        items: ".tt, .ttped",
        track: true
    })
    .toggleClass('tt ttped')
    .trigger('mouseenter');
});
```

I edited your **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfYhu/23/)**, which rebuild tooltip each time you enter on #foo and **[another one](http://jsfiddle.net/yfYhu/25/)** which init tooltip only once (static content)